# Regular Expressions: Match up to a word or a maximum number of words

Tags: python, regex

I want to look for a phrase, match up to a few words following it, but stop early if I find another specific phrase.

For example, I want to match up to three words following "going to the", but stop the matching process if I encounter "to try". So for example "going to the luna park" will result with "luna park"; "going to the capital city of Peru" will result with "capital city of" and "going to the moon to try some cheesecake" will result with "moon".

Can it be done with a single, simple regular expression (preferably in Python)? I've tried all the combinations I could think of, but failed miserably :).

Comment: Please show us your most successfull attempt.

Comment: Just for fun here is a non regex solution: `' '.join(text.split('going to the ')[1].split(' to try')[0].split()[:3])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one matches up to 3 (`{1,3}`) words following `going to the` as long as they are not followed by to try (`(?!to try)`):

```
import re
infile = open("input", "r")
for line in infile:
    m = re.match("going to the ((?:\w+\s*(?!to try)){1,3})", line)
    if m:
        print m.group(1).rstrip()
```

**Output**

```
luna park
capital city of
moon
```

Comment: Why does it work with "going to the beautiful great moon to try cheesecake" and return "beautiful great moon"? I was expecting "moon" to not match, because it is followed by "to try"…

Comment: @EOL Consider "going to the moon to try...": `"moon "` is followed by `to try` and fails the lookahead. Engine backtracks one space and then has a match. Now the next character is space and it does not match `\w`, so you don't get a second word.

Comment: I am confused: my question is about why the given regexp matches *three* words (after "going to the") when they are followed by "to try": I don't understand how the 3rd word matches, since it is followed by "to try", which indeed fails the lookahead…

Comment: @EOL, yes sorry it was me who got confused. The `\s*` has the negative look-ahead restriction so it matches the word but does not match the space

Comment: thanks @perreal, I need this example to internalize the functionality of non-capturing (? ) regexps. Never thought of using them like this.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for a way to extract Proper Nouns out of sentences. You should look at NLTK for proper approach. Regex can be only helpful of a limited context free grammer. On the other hand you seem to asking for ability to parse human language which is non-trivial (for computers).

Comment: If anything, may be better suited as a comment.